# One instruction to load effective address to XMM registers in x86_64?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sse, simd

Is there any way to load the effective address to the `XMM` registers, same as `LEA` for regular registers? If not, what is the fastest solution and how many cycles it would take more.

Comment: Curious why you'd want to load the address of a memory location into an XMM register? Smells like a possible XY problem.

Comment: An `xmm` register is 128-bit vs the 64 bits of an address. Are you looking for an instruction to move a GPR to the low part of an `xmm` register (i.e. `(v)movq`)? I not aware of any `lea` like instruction for XMM, something like `vgatherq` but that doesn't do the loads, just the address generation. FMA are conceptually similar but they work with FP e not integers.

Comment: I am doing a binary transformation and I am trying to abuse the XMM registers to achieve my goal faster instead of saving registers or using memory computations.

Comment: Yes I want to move the 64-bit address to lower bits of XMM register. Even I am interested in the lowest 32bit of the address. Anyway thank you for your comment.

Comment: According to the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2&text=movq&expand=1821) `movq` has a latency of 1 and a reciprocal throughput of 1/3. I guess it is unlikely that this will cause a bottle-neck in your program. You'd need to provide more context to get more definitive answers on that, though ...

Comment: @chtz: That entry in Intel's table is wrong for CPUs after Sandybridge, where Agner Fog's testing for SnB and Nehalem does show movd/movq is 3 per clock.  On IvB/HSW/SKL, only the `movq xmm, xmm` form of `movq` is 3 per clock, zero-extending the low 64-bits of a vector register.  `movq xmm, r64` is 1 uop / 1 per clock, running on port 5 in HSW/SKL.  It also has worse latency on AMD, but still good throughput  (does take 2 uops on Bulldozer-family where 2 integer cores share a SIMD unit).  There's no better solution, though; store/reload isn't better even on Bulldozer-family; also high latency.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, maybe something like this (I know it's not one instruction):

lea rbx, [rax+18]    ; rbx = rax + 18

movq xmm, rbx        ; move rbx into xmm

It's been a while since if looked at these but the best I remember:

lea has a throughput of 0.5 and latency of 1

movq has a throughput of 0.33 and latency of 1

Several of these together would be 2 per clock cycle.

Comment: Yeah, I can do it in two steps using one other register. I wanted to avoid using general registers. But thanks anyway.

Comment: You could store the value to memory and then load directly from memory into a XMM register.

mov QWORD PTR [rbp-32], 8531   ; or a register like rax

movq xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-32]

Comment: Intel's intrinsics guide has wrong throughput numbers for movq; it's only 1 per clock on recent CPUs.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614205/one-instruction-to-load-effective-address-to-xmm-registers-in-x86-64#comment86340018_49614205.  But it doesn't compete for the same execution port as `lea`.  e.g. Haswell runs RIP-relative or 3-component-LEA only on port1, but `movq xmm, r64` only on p5.  (Simple LEA can run on p1 or p5). But you won't have *just* that, so you need to look at surrounding code for bottlenecks on ports.  LEA + MOVQ just costs 2 uops of front-end throughput.